# io.netty.channel.connecttimeoutexception connection timed out

Tags: server, minecraft

after a change in the IP, our server has stopped working. Only the host can connect to the server. we already tried Whitelisting Java and the port, restarted the router, reinstalling java, and even made another complete server. It just stopped working. does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you port forwarded your router correctly?

If not then only connections from your LAN network can connect to the server.

Comment: I mean The server did work before with the same port and we did try port forwarding it again.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced with this problem. because there were no database connection settings in the configuration file in my project. It worked when I added them.

[image]

**for example**

```
db.url=
db.username=
db.password=
db.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
db.tableprefix=
db.pool.maxActive=180
db.pool.maxIdle=180
```